# 'DailySalesReportRQ' responds with an error 'TICKETING DATABASE ERROR'

Tags: sabre

Request to 'DailySalesReport' service responds with an error. What could be the possible reason?

```
            
            security1.BinarySecurityToken = security.BinarySecurityToken;
            var response = client.DailySalesReportRQ(ref messageHeader, ref security1, request.DailySalesReportRQ);
```

I received this error too "ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE".

This is the request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>

-<DailySalesReportRQ Version="2.0.0" TimeStamp="2020-12-13T18:34:56.6500346+03:00" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<SalesReport xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" StartDate="2018-10-01" PseudoCityCode="IPCC1"/>

</DailySalesReportRQ>
```

This is the response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>

-<DailySalesReportRS Version="2.0.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


-<ApplicationResults xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" status="NotProcessed">


-<Error timeStamp="2020-12-19T18:29:41+03:00" type="BusinessLogic">


-<SystemSpecificResults>

<Message>TICKETING DATABASE ERROR</Message>

<ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</ShortText>

</SystemSpecificResults>

</Error>

</ApplicationResults>

</DailySalesReportRS>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Oguzhn,

First of all, you must have a credential to access Sabre's web services, since with this access you should have access to a PCC with the volume of tickets issued, that is, in the CERT.SABRE environment you should have already issued tickets in this PCC.
Once you meet this requirement you will be able to generate daily sales reports with up to 30 days retroactive ie D-30.

In your request you are using the example settings ...

- StartDate="**YYYY-MM-DD**", only the last 30 days
- PseudoCityCode = "**IPCC1**", travel agency sales unit

... in this case you must adjust these values with real information from the travel agency, as you are using the references in the development document.

Here is an example:

```
<SalesReport StartDate="2020-12-20" PseudoCityCode="4DC2"/>
```

You must change **StartDate** and **PseudoCityCode** to your agency's information.